# Wordpress custom metabox for a specific page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is there a way to add a metabox for a specific page, I want the metabox to be displayed only on the page "X" in the admin, is there an argument or something that you can specify in order to achive this?

Comment: I've found a way using $_GET...buy I don't know if it's the best option!

Answer (score 2):

I use the excellent [Core Metabox Library](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) for this purpose.  Its really easy to implement, and can do pretty much anything as far as I can tell.

This is from the relevant [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Display-Options) page:

```
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'contact-information',
        'title' => 'Contact Information',
        'pages' => array('page'), // post type
        'show_on' => array( 'key' => 'id', 'value' => array( 50, 24 ) ),
        'context' => 'normal', //  'normal', 'advanced', or 'side'
        'priority' => 'high',  //  'high', 'core', 'default' or 'low'
        'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
        'fields' => array(
```

**The type of show_on filter (key) is "id"** and the value for that filter is an array of your IDs. If you only wanted it on the About page you could use 'value' => 50 instead of putting it in an array.

If you don't want to use the library, you could find more clues by having a look inside: on line 100 of init.php of the library, it does something like:

```
    if( conditions_met() )
        add_meta_box( params ) ;
```

(Seriously, though - just use it all - it does uploads, tinymce, taxonomies, the works!)

Hope that Helps!
Tim